# drawString and Ellipse2D compatibility issues

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a GUI that I am using drawString to label rows of Ellipse2D objects.  The problem is that both aren't displayed on the same tabbedPane at the same time like I want them to.

QUESTION: Why is this happening?

DrawEllipse.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawEllipses extends JPanel {
    private static final int OVAL_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final Color INACTIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color ACTIVE_COLOR = Color.green;
    private java.util.List<Point> points;
    private java.util.List<Ellipse2D> ellipses = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Ellipse2D, Color> ellipseColorMap = new HashMap<>();

    /*
    * This method is used to populate ellipses with initialized ellipse2D
     */
    public DrawEllipses(java.util.List<Point> points) {
        JLabel outBound = new JLabel("<html><font size=6>External Port</font></html>");
        this.points = points;
        for (Point p : points) {
            int x = p.x - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int y = p.y - OVAL_WIDTH / 2;
            int w = OVAL_WIDTH;
            int h = OVAL_WIDTH;
            Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, w, h);
            ellipses.add(ellipse);
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }

        MyMouseAdapter mListener = new MyMouseAdapter();
        addMouseListener(mListener);
        addMouseMotionListener(mListener);
        add(outBound);
    }

    /*
    * paintComponent is used to paint the ellipses
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
            g2.setColor(ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse));
            g2.fill(ellipse);
        }
    }

    /*
    * MouseAdapter is extended for mousePressed Event that detects if the x, y coordinates
    * of a drawn ellipse are clicked.  If the color is INACTIVE it is changed to ACTIVE and
    * vice versa.
     */
    private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        /*
        * When mousePressed event occurs, the color is toggled between ACTIVE and INACTIVE
         */
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Color c = null;
            for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses) {
                if (ellipse.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    c = (ellipseColorMap.get(ellipse) == INACTIVE_COLOR) ? ACTIVE_COLOR : INACTIVE_COLOR;
                    ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, c);
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    /*
    *Used for button click action to change all ellipses to ACTIVE_COLOR
     */
    public void activateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, ACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    /*
    *Used for button click action to change all ellipses to INACTIVE_COLOR
     */
    public void deactivateAll(){
        for (Ellipse2D ellipse : ellipses){
            ellipseColorMap.put(ellipse, INACTIVE_COLOR);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

DrawString.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class DrawString extends JPanel {

    private static final Color STRING_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    public DrawString() {}

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(STRING_COLOR);
            g.drawString("1", 40, 80);
            g.drawString("2", 40, 160);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like your problem is elsewhere if these methods aren't drawing in the same place. Where to you instantiate and add`DrawString` and `DrawEllipses` to some other object?

Comment: What tabbed pane? The code you show does not contain a TabbedPane. Show us how you are trying to add these two instances to your TabbedPane.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was trying to add to a new tab via action event.  This caused buggy graphic rendering.  I added the string creation unto the draw ellipse method and it works now.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @feltersnach, `I added the string creation unto the draw ellipse method and it works now` - painting methods are for painting only. They should not be used to create other components.

Comment: @camickr I phrased that improperly.  I added the drawString calls to the DrawEllipses method.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably your layout manager. The layout manager is responsible for setting the size/location of each component on the panel.

Also, when you do custom painting you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of each component so the layout manager can use the information to set the size/location of each component. If the size is (0, 0) then there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted in your last question is NOT a SSCCE. We don't need 50 points to demonstrate a concept. You don't need all the actions since they are not related to alignment of components. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the code.